# MSDN links in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, msdn

I'm looking for a plugin or way to simply go from any namespace, type, method, property, etc in my .Net code to the MSDN page that covers it via a context menu item or hyperlink-like mechanism.  Does anyone know of anything that will do that?

The "Go to Definition" option when you right click *almost* covers this, but it doesn't quite work well enough - no support for namespaces and you often end up at an ugly metadata page.  I'm still on vs2005, so if vs2008 is better at this I'd like to know about it.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, it's a great idea for a new addin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried F1.  This will automatically open the help to the appropriate method or object.  Not sure if this works for namespaces.

Comment: F1 uses current cursor context to try to find pages - MMV (depending on what's highlighted) but usually it's pretty good.

Comment: That's probably good enough.  I would have preferred something using a Right-click action, but this will do.

Comment: is there a way to have this open MSDN help in the browser rather than Visual Studio's integrated help viewer

Answer (score 1):

Besides using F1 (which doesn't always work) I haven't found an add-in for VS to do this, I have another quick way around it.

I use Launchy (from launchy.net) and setup the Weby plug-in so I can quickly do MSDN searches. So if I'm looking for String.Format, my keyboard only sequence (from VS, or anywhere else) would be this:

alt-space
MSDN 
String.Format

that brings me right to an MSDN search, where usually the first listing is what I'm looking for.  It's not a perfect solution, but having a fast internet connection and the keyboard only approach works well for me.